# Send email from static sites in docker containers linked by a reverse proxy on Digital Ocean

Tags: php, docker, sendmail

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean. Here, I run several docker containers, each hosting a simple static website. I have them networked to the popular Nginx Reverse proxy container from Jwilder, which routes traffic to the container matching the domain requested.

Now- I want to send mail (e.g. to submit forms) from my static sites, using basic sendmail in a php script.

I am new to these topics, so I am not sure how to achieve this.

I assume I have to somehow map the ports from the containers to the host machine and thus allow mail to pass through. But I have Googled tirelessly and cannot figure out how to achieve this. I have no code to show, but I have read so many things, my brain is spinning, and I am none the wiser.

Comment: You have "no code to show" but have you tried anything? It might help you to find the exact problem. It might be too broad right now

Comment: @SuperDJ I do not have code to show, since I am a bit in the dark as to what I need to do. I am thus not necessarily even looking for code, but rather just for a description of a strategy that I might take.

Comment: A strategy will lead to opinionated answers which is something that SO wants to avoid

Comment: I understand that concern, but please also see my situation- I am new to docker and mail servers, so my search results explaining fine nuances of setting up SMTP servers fly over my head. I just need something along the lines of -"Hey, I have a similar setup in terms of multiple domain containers with a reverse proxy, here's the stack that I'm using to send mail"